# Magento CE 1.9.1 I need to set some products to ship ground

Tags: magento-1.9

Some of my products have to be shipped via Ground the others can be shipped express, is there a way to set this up in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the table rates shipping method to set up rules for shipping carriers.